# consuming conan latest version

Tags: version, conan

We are working on integration of conan package management into our pipeline.

Our conan package are store in Artifactory.

The convention of our version numbers looks like this:

> Minor.Major.Patch-BuildVerison

As we know, for consuming the latest version, need to use

> [> Minor.Major.Patch]

into the conanfile.py.

The only way we were able to get a latest version from versions like our convention is to write it like this:

> [> Minor.Major.Patch-0]

But our problem happens in situations like the example below:

Let's say these are the version numbers of a package that we try to consume it's latest version:

> 1.2.3-1
>
> 1.2.3-2
>
> 1.2.3-3

if we write in our conanfile.py

> [>1.2.3-0]

we will get the

> 1.2.3-3

as well.

But if we upload the version

> 1.2.4-1

of thus package (only update the Patch number), and we leave the conanfile.py as is - we will still get the

> 1.2.3-3

not the

> 1.2.4-1

as accepted.

Please help us know what is the best way to get what we want.

Thanks.

Comment: Follow up github issue: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/3997

Comment: Thanks, but it's my issue

Answer (score 1):

Conan v.1.10 introduced two new options associated with version ranges ([from the docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/mastering/version_ranges.html)):

- **loose**: to include/exclude valid semver string checking (defaulted to True)
- **include_prerelease**: to include/exclude prerelease versions in the search range (defaulted to False)

Use these options to have more fine-grained control over requirements:

```
class HelloConan(ConanFile):
   requires = "Pkg/[~1.2.3,loose=False,include_prerelease=True]@user/stable"
```